# Get formula cell value in openpyxl 2.0.3

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

I want to access real value of a cell using openpyxl 2.0.3.

I have a cell which has a formula value like `= V1/40`
I want to access it resultant value which we would see when we open the excel.
I was trying to access it via interal_value property but it returns None all the time even while opening the workbook with `data_only = True`.

I had stumbled upon [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/openpyxl-users/g3PQIpqzBnA/xtHBASolVE0J)

Which talks about `worksheet.cached_value["A25"]` but this gives an attribute error.

Does anyone have any idea of how can I get these values?

Answer (score 0):

2.0.x contains a bug that means the value for some cells with formulae (both formula and value) are None. This has been fixed in both the 2.0 and 2.1 branches and should be released shortly. Please checkout one of the versions and try it with your file.